# Worpress site: after duplicator migration homepage and login gives error "too many redirects"

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, migration

I'm migrating a wordpress site from a host to another and I'm using Duplicator plugin to do so.
After migrating, it allows me to see all the pages except the homepage and the login page. It says that has too many redirect.
Mapping the redirect for the home, it's been redirected because of error 301 "Moved permanently"; while the login is just not found.

I tried all the common solution found on the internet for this kind of problem:

- removed the cookies
- deleted the .htaccess
- renamed active theme folder
- remamed plugin folder
- set in config.php the WP_SITENAME and WP_HOME urls

but the error is still there.

Comment: First you could try in a different browser, just to make sure the redirect was not cached. Then you could use [one](https://redirects.show/) [of the services](https://www.redirect-checker.org/) that list the redirects so that you see which path they take. If your site is already online, you could also post the URL here.

Comment: Yes, forgot to write that down too, but already tested in other browsers, same thing for using the service for mapping the redirects, it seems the homepage always redirects to itself. Now I'm trying to migrate again ( duplicator offers the possibility to go back luckily).
I'm making an idea that it could be due to the fact that the original site run on http, while on the server i'm migrating to, everything run on https, so maybe that's the reason for the redirects. As soon as the migration ends I'll check this route too.

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked. Apparently, creating a package from Duplicator lite and importing it on Duplicator Pro doesn't work so well. Activated a license on my localhost with Duplicator Pro and exported it and worked out totally fine on the first try. Pretty curious about this though.